# Cannot call class method

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a class method by first obtaining a copy from the List.
Separately, the method works correctly.

```
class testCandidate:
    voitingSistem=VoitingSystem()
    voitingSistem.addCandidate("Putin")
    candidate=Candidate("Putin")
    print(candidate.GetName())
    print(voitingSistem.voiting.getCandidate(0).GetName())
```

OUT:

> Traceback (most recent call last): Putin   File
>   "E:/Dropbox/Pyton/Network/Client-Server/Server/testCandidate.py", line
>   5, in 
>       class testCandidate:   File "E:/Dropbox/Pyton/Network/Client-Server/Server/testCandidate.py", line
>   10, in testCandidate
>       print(voitingSistem.voiting.getCandidate(0).GetName()) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'GetName'

```
class VoitingSystem:
    users=[];
    voiting="";

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.voiting=Voiting("Voiting1");
        super().__init__()

    def addCandidate(self, name):
        candidate=Candidate(name)
        self.voiting.candidats.append(candidate)
        return None


    def getCandidate(self,index):
        return self.voiting.getCandidate(index)


class Voiting(object):
    name=""
    candidats=[]

    def __init__(self,Name) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.name=Name


    def getCandidates(self):
        return self.candidats;

    def getCandidate(self,index) -> Candidate:
        return self.candidats[index];

    def addCandidate(self,Name):
        self.candidats.append(Name)


class Candidate:
    name="";
    voices=0;

    def __init__(self,Name):
        self.name=Name;
        self.voices=0;


    def SetName(self,Name):
        self.name=Name;

    def GetName(self):
        return self.name;
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: also can you fix the indentation?

Comment: Why is `testCandidate` even a class? It only needs to be a function, if not just bare module-level code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`candidats` is a list of names.  You cannot retrieve a name (string) and use that directly to invoke a method of a user-defined class.  You haven't defined your purpose very well, but I suspect that what you want is for the class to hold a list of candidate objects.  In this case, you'll want something like:

```
def addCandidate(self, candidate):
    self.candidats.append(self, candidate)
```

Pass it the instance rather than the name.